# How to enable Ruby Language Runtime Metrics for container (stack: container) applications at Heroku

Tags: ruby, heroku

We use Heroku for hosting some of our applications, and we would like to have the Language Runtime Metrics that they provide in their metrics dashboard for each app.

I did everything according to the Ruby Language Metrics "[Getting Started](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/language-runtime-metrics-ruby#getting-started)" article but the metrics won't show up.

My apps are in `stack: container` instead of `heroku-18` or `heroku-16` stacks.

They say:

> This process does not work with container based-applications because they do not use buildpacks. Currently container-based applications are not supported in this beta.

Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

After speaking with Heroku's support we found a way to make it work. We’re using an Alpine docker image:

1. We added `bash` and `curl` to our Dockerfile (`apk add bash curl`)
2. We copied the [`heroku-metrics-daemon.sh`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-metrics)  to `/etc/profile.d/` to run as a `profile.d` script on the boot of the Heroku dyno.
3. We needed to edit the `.sh` file:

   1. We removed the `--warning=no-unknown-keyword` flag from the tar command. Apparently it’s not compatible with the Alpine tar, only GNU tar. You could also add GNU tar to your image.
   2. We had problems with the array parsing/syntax in the script, even with `bash` installed and with `#!/bin/bash`, so we removed the option to use `AGENTMON_DEBUG` from the script.

The final script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

# From: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-metrics/blob/master/.profile.d/heroku-metrics-daemon.sh
setup_metrics() {
    # don't do anything if we don't have a metrics url.
    if [[ -z "$HEROKU_METRICS_URL" ]] || [[ "${DYNO}" = run\.* ]]; then
        return 0
    fi

    STARTTIME=$(date +%s)
    BUILD_DIR=/tmp

    DOWNLOAD_URL=$(curl --retry 3 -s https://agentmon-releases.s3.amazonaws.com/latest)
    if [ -z "${DOWNLOAD_URL}" ]; then
        echo "!!!!! Failed to find latest agentmon. Please report this as a bug. Metrics collection will be disabled this run."
        return 1
    fi

    BASENAME=$(basename "${DOWNLOAD_URL}")

    curl -L --retry 3 -s -o "${BUILD_DIR}/${BASENAME}" "${DOWNLOAD_URL}"

    # Ensure the bin folder exists, if not already.
    mkdir -p "${BUILD_DIR}/bin"

    # Extract agentmon release
    # tar --warning=no-unknown-keyword -C "${BUILD_DIR}/bin" -zxf "${BUILD_DIR}/${BASENAME}"
    tar -C "${BUILD_DIR}/bin" -zxf "${BUILD_DIR}/${BASENAME}"
    chmod +x "${BUILD_DIR}/bin/agentmon"

    ELAPSEDTIME=$(($(date +%s) - STARTTIME))
    echo "agentmon setup took ${ELAPSEDTIME} seconds"

    # AGENTMON_FLAGS=("-statsd-addr=:${PORT}")
    AGENTMON_FLAG="-statsd-addr=:${PORT}"


    # if [[ "${AGENTMON_DEBUG}" = "true" ]]; then
    #     AGENTMON_FLAGS+=("-debug")
    # fi

    if [[ -x "${BUILD_DIR}/bin/agentmon" ]]; then
        (while true; do
            # ${BUILD_DIR}/bin/agentmon "${AGENTMON_FLAGS[@]}" "${HEROKU_METRICS_URL}"
            ${BUILD_DIR}/bin/agentmon "${AGENTMON_FLAG}" "${HEROKU_METRICS_URL}"
            echo "agentmon completed with status=${?}. Restarting"
            sleep 1
        done) &
    else
        echo "No agentmon executable found. Not starting."
    fi
}
setup_metrics
```